# Memory leak using logging from QThread using PyQt4 and PySide, but not from Python threads, in Windows

Tags: logging, pyqt4, pyside, python-multithreading

When using the "logging" module from within a QThread, I see memory leakage when running in Windows. This happens both using PySide and PyQt4 in Python 3.

In Linux, there is no memory leakage.

The program below demonstrates the issue. It can be called in three ways.

Running without arguments uses Python threads and shows no leakage:

```
D:\> python MemoryLeak.py
gc objects: 8965
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 8987
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 8987
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 8987
WARNING:root:hi there!
(... etcetera ...)
```

Running with a single "--qt" argument uses QThreads via Qt4 and leaks in Windows but not in Linux:

```
D:\>python MemoryLeak.py  --qt
gc objects: 8975
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 9000
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 9010
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 9020
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 9030
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 9040
WARNING:root:hi there!
(... etcetera ...)
```

Running with "--qt" and "--pyside" arguments uses QThreads via PySide and leaks in Windows but not in Linux:

```
D:\>python MemoryLeak.py  --qt --pyside
gc objects: 15076
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 15093
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 15103
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 15113
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 15123
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 15133
WARNING:root:hi there!
gc objects: 15143
(... etcetera...)
```

I am using WinPython 3.3.5 under Windows, which is based on Python 3.3.5.

My full test program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys, time, logging, gc, threading

if "--pyside" in sys.argv:
    from PySide import QtCore
    QtSlot = QtCore.Slot
else:
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
    QtSlot = QtCore.pyqtSlot

def gc_status():
    gc.collect(0)
    gc.collect(1)
    gc.collect(2)
    print("gc objects:", len(gc.get_objects()))

class MyQtThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def run(self):
        logging.warning("hi there!")

class MyQtApplication(QtCore.QCoreApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._count = 0
        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self._timer_timeout)
        self._timer.start(200)

    @QtSlot()
    def _timer_timeout(self):
        gc_status()
        t = MyQtThread()
        t.start()
        t.wait()
        self._count += 1
        if self._count == 50:
            self.quit()

def qt_main():
    app = MyQtApplication(sys.argv)
    app.exec_()

class PythonThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def run(self):
        logging.warning("hi there!")

def python_main():
    for i in range(50):
        gc_status()
        t = PythonThread()
        t.start()
        t.join()
        time.sleep(0.200)

if "--qt" in sys.argv:
    qt_main()
else:
    python_main()
```

Is this a known issue/bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just tried Python 2.7 (latest PyQt4) and saw the same thing. I think it is likely a problem with the logging module rather than PyQt/PySide. I profiled what is leaking and it is a bunch of Python dictionaries and lists, so I guess the logging module doesn't know how to clean up after itself if it is used outside of a Python thread.

Comment: I tried with PySide 1.2.2 on Python 3.4.2 64 bit on Windows 7 and do not see a leak.